# Help w/ Executing MS Flow from an SPFX Command Extension Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, flow, button

I have a manual trigger Flow setup that gets a SharePoint List, creates an HTML table of the list and formats it, then emails it to some people. I have gone through all the Microsoft documentation to setup a button using the SPFX Command Extension but for the life of me cannot figure out to call that Flow from the button being clicked. I have also looked through some article online but all are using Get an HTTP Request and using it for something different besides just clicking a button to run a Flow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction!